# I can't to connect to DB with ssh-tunnel using java.

Tags: java, mysql, database, ssh-tunnel

i have sql-BD with ssh-tunnel. i want connect to this BD using Java

the code i use:

```
    Connection con = null;
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    int localPort = 1234;

    Session session = jsch.getSession(proxyUser, proxyHost, 22);
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.setPassword(proxyPassword);

    session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
    session.connect();
    session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, proxyHost, 3306);


    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("user", user);
    properties.setProperty("password", password);
    properties.setProperty("useUnicode", "true");
    properties.setProperty("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://" + url + ":3306/" + nameBD + "?autoReconnect=true", properties);
```

Error line ***"Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up"***

Error while executing this:
"**con = DriverManager.getConnection(...)**"

Help me please

Answer (score 0):

Debugging something like this is probably best done with [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), which will allow you to see what's actually happening on the wire, and quickly work out what's *not quite right (tm)*. If you're not familiar with the tool, there are plenty of [tutorials](https://www.lifewire.com/wireshark-tutorial-4143298) around to choose from.

I think that mostly you just need to get things to match and it'll work ok:

- `LocalPort` is currently set to `1234`, but `DriverManager.getConnection`
  is trying to connect to `3306`.
- The script snippet is incomplete, so I assume that `url` is set to
  localhost/127.0.0.1 elsewhere ...
- `jsch.getSession` and `session.setPortForwardingL` both use `proxyHost` as a destination: I assume you have a firewall on the host (which is why you're using ssh) so trying to connect locally to the external interface address may also be blocked. Which means that `session.setPortForwardingL` should probably be localhost/127.0.0.1 too.

Comment: i change port in DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://" + url + ":" + localPort + "/"+ nameBD + "?autoReconnect=true", properties ), and use url  istead proxyHost in session.setPortForwardingL, but the error remained
My be there is another solution?

Comment: Have you manually checked everything works: the SSH connection establishes ok (check logs on the proxy host); the local redirect port is open and listening (netstat); and a connection to the local port reaches the remote mysql instance (telnet will work ok)